# "Кто бы" или "кем бы"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Как правильно написать: "Кто бы ни был этот человек?" или "Кем бы ни был этот человек?". Если можно — с обоснованием.

Comment: Праильны оба варианта. Вопрос надо ставить о различии между ними. Для правильного выбора в каждом конкретном случае нужен контекст.

Comment: @М_Г  , “Кто бы ни был этот Капитан Америка, я его не одобряю.”

Answer (score 1):

> Кто бы ни был этот Капитан Америка, я его не одобряю.

Вы не знаете, кто скрывается за прозвищем Капитан Америка? Тогда "кто бы он ни был". Если вы не знаете, что он из себя представляет (профессия, человеческие качества), то "кем бы он ни был".